# Как привести цифры к одному формату?

Tags: javascript

есть  разные цифры :

```
1, 1.0001, 4, 2.304 , 3.002, 5.1
```

Нужно привести их к одному формату:

```
0.00 
напр `1.00, 1.01 , 4.00,5.10`
```

Есть ли какие нибудь встроенные функции?

Answer (score 1):

N.toFixed(2)

```js
document.write(Number('2').toFixed(2));
document.write('<br>')
document.write(Number('3.005').toFixed(2))
```

Comment: Документация - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed